# def __str__(self): return str(self.name) in model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my models.py.  def **str**(self):return str(self.name) still won't change Product object (1) to the product name.

```
from cgi import print_exception
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    # image =
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2,  null=True, blank=True)
    countInStock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

Comment: self.name has null=True and Null is not a string...

Answer (score 1):

You should define [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method inside the class, also use [`f`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) strings so:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    # image =
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2,  null=True, blank=True)
    countInStock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

Comment: name is a CharField, so he doesn't need to user f string.

Comment: @hiwa It's good practice to use `f` strings, also see there `null=True` then it will return None.

Comment: I'm getting the error even without the null=True

Answer (score 0):

if your `__str__` not work and you receive a Object (1), it mean you use repr(obj). Therefore you should override `__repr__` method.

```
def __repr__(self): 
    return f'{self.name}'
```